# Compile a kernel module for RPI

Tags: raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to  compile a "Hello Word" kernel module using the Raspberry Pi2. I have installed rpi-source.

Here is the Makefile I am using:

```
obj-m += hello.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

But I didn't receive a hello.ko file. Here is the my result:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.7-v7+/build M= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/linux-cd560b8658868d9652ab31754e02f86daf6831ba'
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[2]: 'include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
  CHK     include/generated/bounds.h
  CHK     include/generated/timeconst.h
  CHK     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CHK     kernel/config_data.h
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1471 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/linux-cd560b8658868d9652ab31754e02f86daf6831ba
```

Can you help me?